# Facebook SDK3.0 how to use WebDialog without picture

Tags: android, facebook

I referenced the sample code from Facebook SDK3.0, using WebDialog to post story on my wall.

The sample code demonstrate the Bundle object use to construct WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
```

so i change some words to test in my project:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Push test");
params.putString("caption", "hello");
params.putString("description", "hello");
params.putString("link", "");
params.putString("picture", "");
```

but the result of "name", "caption", "description" on WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder are 
disappeared

then i found the value of `params.putString("picture", "");`

with invalid URL or empty String, the WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder will not work.

with empty String:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Test");
params.putString("caption", "hello");
params.putString("description", "hello");
params.putString("link", "");
params.putString("picture", "");
```

[image]

with invalid url:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Test");
params.putString("caption", "hello");
params.putString("description", "hello");
params.putString("link", "");
params.putString("picture", "null");
```

[image]

with any valid url:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "test");
params.putString("caption", "hello");
params.putString("description", "hello");
params.putString("link", "");
params.putString("picture", "http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Google-Apps.jpeg");
```

[image]

Use just three parameters:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "test");
params.putString("caption", "hello");
params.putString("description", "hello");
```

[image]

so, how should i pass the correct value to `params.putString("picture", "");`

can make it work without picture?

Comment: if don't want the picture than remove the line params.putString("picture", "");

Comment: If remove the params.putString("picture", "");, the result of WebDialog will shows like the first picture i post above, the "name", "caption" and "description" are disappeared

Comment: dont use the parameters with empty string

Comment: the WebDialog work with one parameter as well as

Comment: the "name", "caption" and "description" are disappeared when i just use that three parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is you don't have any value for "link".

"name", "caption", "description" and "picture" all apply to the link field. I don't know why anything gets displayed when you have a value for "picture" but not "link", but I'm pretty sure the problem is because you don't have "link".

Comment: But i don't have any link that i want to post on the wall, when the "link" parameter is set, "name", "caption" and "description" are displayed, but i don't want to show any link in this story

Comment: If you don't have a "link", then you don't get to set "name", "caption", or "description". That's just how the share dialog works.

Comment: OK, so how should i post some words on the wall via Facebook sdk 3.0?

Comment: If you want to post a message, you can use the Graph API, and request publish_stream permissions to post directly to a user's timeline. The feed dialog is mainly to share links/pictures/media, and does not allow the app to set the message.

Comment: Dose it have any complete example or tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android"); // required filed
params.putString("picture", "");
```

Comment: I tried, but the result will be the first picture i post above